# XSD not validating - udemy in28minutes

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, xsd, xsd-validation

When I change the ID value to alpha characters - it doesn't tell me the values are invalid...

**course-details.xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
targetNamespace="http://in28minutes.com/courses" 
xmlns:tns="http://in28minutes.com/courses" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <element name="GetCourseDetailsRequest">
        <complexType>
            <sequence>
                <element name= "id" type="integer"></element>
            </sequence> 
        </complexType>
    </element>
</schema>
```

**Request.xml** I expect an error to show on the `<id>` line...

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <GetCourseDetailsRequest xmlns="http://in28minutes.com/courses" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://in28minutes.com/courses course-details.xsd" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <id>abc</id> <!-- numbers  -->
    </GetCourseDetailsRequest>
```

The files are in the same folder - so not sure why this doesn't work:

[image]

Comment: Well, Eclipse won't check that. What happens when you actually send the request?

Comment: You need to run a validation tool on your xml. All the IDE (eclipse) will do Is make sure your structure is followed so your xml is well-formed.

Comment: @Benson99 how would I run a validation tool?

Comment: I don't use eclipse, but in netbeans I simply right-click on on the xml file and choose "validate".  Eclipse probably has some similar functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely don't have the Validation builder on the project, or aren't letting the project build (which would automatically validate your XML files).

Open the project's Properties dialog and go to the Validation page. The option to add it should be there.

EDIT: You should also be able to right-click on the file and manually Validate it.